# How do I check if a given path is relative or absolute in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, relative-path

I have this function that will handle relative paths by converting them to absolute.

```
Public Function ifRelativeConvertToAbsolutePath(path As String) As String

    If (isPathRelative(path)) Then
        ifRelativeConvertToAbsolutePath = convertToAbsolutePath(path)
    Else
        ifRelativeConvertToAbsolutePath = path
    End If

End Function
```

How could I implement the `isPathRelative` function?

My ideas include:

- Check if the path starts with "\"
- Check if there are any "\" in the string

Comment: any reason you can't just call `convertToAbsolutePath` regardless of whether `path` is relative or not?

Comment: I have implemented `convertToAbsolutePath` myself.  It basically concatanates the path to the end of `ThisWorkBook.Path`

Comment: That method won't work it the relative path contains segments like `\..\..\..\Program Files\etc`

Comment: If you're running on Windows (I've no experience of Office for Mac) you can just include a reference to the Scripting runtime and use `Scripting.FileSystemObject`'s `GetAbsolutePathName(path)` regardless of `path`'s relativity. Simpler, already implemented and compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it starts with "\" (that includes "\" for UNC) or with 1 letter + ":\"

```
Function IsPathRel(p As String) As Boolean
    IsPathRel = Not ((Left(p, 3) Like "[A-Z]:\") Or (Left(p, 1) = "\"))
End Function
```

Comment: I am confused by `(Left(p, 1) = "\")`.  If this bit is checking for network paths then surelly they start with "\\", so souldnt it be `(Left(p, 2) = "\\")`

Comment: an UNC starts with "\\", but a local drive path can start with "\" if you omit the drive letter. So yes, a path starting with a single "\" is always absolute.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a shell API for that ([`PathIsRelative`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), or there is `PathCombine` which will automatically convert a rel path to an abs path if it receives one;

```
Private Declare Function PathCombine Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathCombineA" (ByVal szDest As String, ByVal lpszDir As String, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long

Dim sBuff As String * 255
PathCombine sBuff, "C:\theroot\xxx\", "..\jibblets"
x = Left$(sBuff, InStr(1, sBuff, vbNullChar) - 1)

== "C:\theroot\jibblets"

PathCombine sBuff, "C:\theroot\xxx\", "X:\foo.bar"

== "X:\foo.bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you did the following:

```
If not Dir( thisWorkbook.Path & "\" & path, vbDirectory) = vbNullString then
     ifRelativeConvertToAbsolutePath = thisWorkbook.Path & "\" & path
else
     ifRelativeConvertToAbsolutePath = path
end if
```

Basically, try concatenating the paths. If it results in a valid path, then it was a relative path and you just fixed it, if it does not result in a valid path, then you cannot use that method to fix the path, so just return the path as it was.

Comment: This doesn't work because when you concatenate two absolute paths it will not  conform to operating system conventions as well as Basic file-naming conventions, and the function will cause an error.